# Style a class inside a class but not the outside with the same class

Tags: html, css

I have two divs that has the class `.body`, however, one is inside another div with a class .box - as follows:

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="body">
   </div>
</div>

<div class="body">
</div>
```

I only want to style the .body that is inside of .box... but what I am doing below isn't working and it is applying the styling to the .body out side as well.

```
.box .body {
   background-color: red;
}
```

I don't want to change .box to #box as "box" MAY be placed more than once in the same document.

**Please take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/H2cmE/**

Comment: What's wrong with your fiddle demo?

Answer (score 1):

Well the CSS is actually valid and would only apply styling to any elements with class .body that reside in another element with class .box. We'd need to see your complete html structure to understand why this isn't working in your case.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    green box
   <div class="body">
        inside .box ( it will be red box)
   </div>
</div>

<div class="body">
    not inside .box ( it will be blue box)
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box .body {
   background-color: red;

}

.box {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-color: green;
}

.body {
    width:400px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: blue;    

}
```

[***See demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/BfLGL/)

Answer (score 1):

- .box>div.body
- .box:first-child
- .box div.body

If you want to read more about css selector, go to this website:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

I hope it can help you solve your problem.